# How to mark selected days by time of the day

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to show which day a user is available and weather in morning, afternoon or evening.

I'm getting array of value for each time per user:

morning: array(Mon,Tue,Fri)
afternoon:array()//not available
evening:array(Thrs)

Now my task is, to convert the 3 or 4 letter words into 1 letter and add a green color to the font.

By default, its shown all the days in a week with grey color.The day when user is available only will be marked in green.
[image]

My script:

I'm passing each array namely for morning, afternoon and evening to functions in the ajax success function.

```
         if(globalStore.data[i].morning!=""){

        splitThis_morn(globalStore.data[i].morning);

        }else if(globalStore.data[i].afternoon !="")
        {
                   splitThis_aft(globalStore.data[i].afternoon,globalStore.data[i].UUID);

        }else if(globalStore.data[i].evening !="")
        {

        splitThis_eve(globalStore.data[i].evening,globalStore.data[i].UUID);

        }

function splitThis_morn(param)//this is to split 
{
    var days = param.split(',');//
   // how to do the rest of the work here?

}
function splitThis_aft(param)//this is to split 
{
    var days = param.split(',');//
   // how to do the rest of the work here?

}
function splitThis_eve(param)//this is to split 
{
    var days = param.split(',');//
   // how to do the rest of the work here?

}
```

HTML (1 letter word for days is shown with grey color by default)

```
<div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left morning'>Morning: <span class='mon'>M </span><span class='tue'>T </span><span class='wed'>W </span><span class='thrs'>T </span><span class='fri'>F </span><span class='sat'>S </span><span class='sun'>S</span></div>
```

EDITED ANSWER BASED ON Onheiron's answer

in ajax success fucntion passing to function like this:

```
if(globalStore.data[i].morning!=""){
    splitThis_morn(globalStore.data[i].morning);
    }else if(globalStore.data[i].afternoon !="")
    {
    splitThis_aft(globalStore.data[i].afternoon);
    }else if(globalStore.data[i].evening !="")
    {
    splitThis_eve(globalStore.data[i].evening);
    }
```

the functions:

```
  function splitThis_morn(param)
    {
        var days = param.split(',');

        var morning = days;

    for(d in morning){
        var day = morning[d]
        $('.morning > .'+day.toLowerCase()).addClass('green')
    }
    }


    function splitThis_aft(param)
    {
        var days = param.split(',');

        var afternoon = days;

    for(d in afternoon){
        var day = afternoon[d]
        $('.afternoon > .'+day.toLowerCase()).addClass('green')
    }


    }
    function splitThis_eve(param)
    {
        var days = param.split(',');


        var evening = days;

        for(d in evening){
        var day = evening[d]
        $('.evening > .'+day.toLowerCase()).addClass('green')
    }


    }
```

EDITED ANSWER BASED ON Sahil's

```
activateDays(globalStore.data[i].morning, "morning", globalStore.data[i].UUID);
```

The function

```
function activateDays(activeOn, time, divId){
        activeOn = activeOn.join(',').split(',');
      //assuming that the span tags for morning,afternoon, evening are inside a div with an unique id.
      $('#'+divId +' .'+time+' span').removeClass('active');
       for(i=0;i<activeOn.length;i++){
           var element = days.indexOf(activeOn[i])+1;
           $('#'+divId +' .'+time+' span:nth-child('+element+')').addClass('active');
       }
    }
```

The HTML appended via jquery within ajax success function:

```
<div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-left'> Availability:</div><div  id="+globalStore.data[i].UUID+" class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left morning days'>Morning: <span class='mon'>M </span><span class='tue'>T </span><span class='wed'>W </span><span class='thrs'>T </span><span class='fri'>F </span><span class='sat'>S </span><span class='sun'>S</span></div><div id="+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"  class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left afternoon days'>Afternoon: <span class='mon'>M </span><span class='tue'>T </span><span class='wed'>W </span><span class='thrs'>T </span><span class='fri'>F </span><span class='sat'>S </span><span class='sun'>S</span></div><div id="+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"  class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left evening days'>Evening: <span class='mon'>M </span><span class='tue'>T </span><span class='wed'>W </span><span class='thrs'>T </span><span class='fri'>F </span><span class='sat'>S </span><span class='sun'>S</span></div>
```

Comment: Can you fiddle it? and rephrase what your aiming again..

Comment: @choz here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/7pdqoc7a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat","Sun"];

function activateDays(data, time){
    
  $('.'+time+' span').removeClass('active');
   for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
       var element = days.indexOf(data[i])+1;
       $('.'+time+' span:nth-child('+element+')').addClass('active');
   }
}
 activateDays(["Mon","Wed"],"morning");
    activateDays(["Mon","Thur","Sat"],"afternoon");
    activateDays(["Mon","Thur","Sun","Fri"],"evening");
    });
```

```css
.days{
  background: #333;
  width: auto;
  color: #999;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.active{
  color:turquoise;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="morning days">
  <span>M</span>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>W</span>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>F</span>
  <span>S</span>
  <span>S</span>
</div>
<div class="afternoon days">
  <span>M</span>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>W</span>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>F</span>
  <span>S</span>
  <span>S</span>
</div>
<div class="evening days">
  <span>M</span>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>W</span>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>F</span>
  <span>S</span>
  <span>S</span>
</div>
```

**Updated**
It is easier to do it for each user, you will definitely have **id** for each div inside which you have the span tags. So you can call the function like this from inside of the success event from an ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Do not change this variable's format, this is used below for comparison, just change the spellings of the days if needed.
var days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thrs","Fri","Sat","Sun"];
//example ajax call:
$.ajax({
url: 'example.com',
success: function(data){
//I am assuming data is "Mon,Wed"
 activateDays(data, "morning", divId);
},
error: function(data){
//handle error
}
});
    function activateDays(activeOn, time, divClass){
        activeOn = activeOn.split(',');
      //assuming that the span tags for morning,afternoon, evening are inside a div with an unique id.
      $('.'+divClass +'.'+time+' span').removeClass('active');
       for(i=0;i<activeOn.length;i++){
           var element = days.indexOf(activeOn[i])+1;
           $('.'+divClass +'.'+time+' span:nth-child('+element+')').addClass('active');
       }
    }

  });
```

Comment: I simply copied your js and css. It seems like no error and results are shown. However the color of the letters are not changed.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I properly call the function from the ajax sucess and pass the parameter which is array. One more important thing, I have many users to display on a page. SO the availability (days) must change color per user

Comment: So are you passing an array into the function which I wrote or a string, is it like this **activateDays("Mon,Tue,Wed,Thur","morning")** or like this **activateDays(["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur"],"morning")**? Also please change the days name in the variable **days**.

Comment: Here is the link for live site. I haven't updated your code here as I try in localhost first. This is to give you notion on what I mean by availability per user.  https://dev.gloopal.com//homepage.php

Comment: It has to be like this: var days = ["Mon,Sun,Sat,Fri,Thrs"]; I changed in the days array accordingly but still no color applied

Comment: No posts are shown and the error in the console is: Uncaught TypeError: activeOn.join is not a function

Comment: what's the value of the **activeOn** variable which you are passing inside the **activateDays** function.

Comment: activeOn ->globalStore.data[i].morning (array for morning) = Wed,Thrs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93143/discussion-between-sahil-and-vani).

Answer (score 1):

If I got what you want to do right, this should work fine:

1. Convert strings to arrays
2. For each day in each array, select the right children in the right div
3. Give that children a green color

So if your HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left morning'>
 Morning: 
    <span class='mon'>M </span>
    <span class='tue'>T </span>
    <span class='wed'>W </span>
    <span class='thrs'>T </span>
    <span class='fri'>F </span>
    <span class='sat'>S </span>
    <span class='sun'>S</span>
</div>

<div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left afternoon'>
 Afternoon: 
    <span class='mon'>M </span>
    <span class='tue'>T </span>
    <span class='wed'>W </span>
    <span class='thrs'>T </span>
    <span class='fri'>F </span>
    <span class='sat'>S </span>
    <span class='sun'>S</span>
</div>

<div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left evening'>
 Evening: 
    <span class='mon'>M </span>
    <span class='tue'>T </span>
    <span class='wed'>W </span>
    <span class='thrs'>T </span>
    <span class='fri'>F </span>
    <span class='sat'>S </span>
    <span class='sun'>S</span>
</div>
```

Then you can use some nice jQuery selectors to select the right children in the right list:

```
for(d in morning){
    var day = morning[d]
    if(day.length > 0){
        $('.morning > .'+day.toLowerCase()).addClass('green')
    }
}
```

Note `day.toLowerCase()` converts `Mon` to `mon` which is the correct class name of your span.

[Here a working fiddle for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/7pdqoc7a/1/)

Comment: thanks for the fiddle. When I implement this on the real site, is says: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .morning > .,

Comment: that's  some pollution due to the split part of the original comma separated string. Can you post it here so I can check for correct splitting? Something like `morning = 'Mon,Tue,Fri'`

Comment: ... Or I guess you did something like `for(d in globalStore.data[i].morning)...`? In that case you still need to split the comma separated string `globalStore.data[i].morning` in order to get the correct `morning` array...

Comment: I posted teh code, could you check? now it says Uncaught TypeError: day.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: almost there... can you log the value of day before the jQuery selection? like `console.log(day)`, also log `globalStore.data[i].afternoon` let's see... there should be some undefined somewhere.

Comment: for afternoon= afternoon= Wed,Thrs

Comment: Oh yeah did I tell you that multiple users' availability shown in signle page. So might be some users data undefined for certain time of day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93136/discussion-between-vani-and-onheiron).